# Getting the source of geolocation coordinates

Tags: react-native, geolocation

When using geolocation in react-native, or perhaps any framework that uses geolocation, is it possible to get the source of the coordinates? That is, can I test whether the coordinates came from the GPS satellites, cell tower, or WiFi?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. See the docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html